# In angular how to pass two variable in URL?

Tags: angular

I am making a form with file upload file , When submiting the form then only form input data insert in database and file do not upload please help me how to insert both together?
Below are attached my code employee.component.ts and employee.component.html please see code and answer the this problem.

```
  employee.component.ts


import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {AppService} from '../app.service';
import {User} from '../users';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'; 
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-employees',
  templateUrl: './employees.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employees.component.css']
})
export class EmployeesComponent implements OnInit {
  form:any = {};
  msg: string = null;
  users: User[];
  filedata:any;

  fileEvent(e){
    this.filedata = e.target.files[0];
  }
  constructor(public http: HttpClient,private appService:AppService,private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onSubmit(f:NgForm){ 
    var myFormData = new FormData();
    //console.log(this.form);
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
          headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
          headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
          myFormData.append('image', this.filedata);
          this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employee',myFormData, {
  headers: headers

}).subscribe(users => { users = users});

  }


}
```

emoloyee.component.html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="textColor">{{ msg }}</div>
<h2>Angular Form</h2><br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <form name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm" novalidate action="/">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">User Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" [class.is-invalid]="username.invalid && username.touched" name="username" [(ngModel)]="form.username" #username="ngModel"
              [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': f.submitted && username.invalid}" required placeholder="Enter your user name"/>
            <div *ngIf="f.submitted && username.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
              <div *ngIf="username.errors.required">>> required</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" [(ngModel)]="form.email" #email="ngModel" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': f.submitted && email.invalid}" [class.is-invalid]="email.invalid && email.touched"
              required email placeholder="Enter your email address"/>
            <div *ngIf="f.submitted && email.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
              <div *ngIf="email.errors.required">>> required</div>
              <div *ngIf="email.errors.email">>> must be a valid email address</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="mobile">Mobile</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control" name="mobile" [(ngModel)]="form.mobile" #mobile="ngModel"
                [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': f.submitted && mobile.invalid}" required placeholder="Enter your mobile" pattern="[789][0-9]{9}" minlength="10" [class.is-invalid]="mobile.invalid && mobile.touched"/>
              <div *ngIf="f.submitted && mobile.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
                <div *ngIf="mobile.errors.required">>> required</div>
                <div *ngIf="mobile.errors.pattern">>>Please enter a valid mobile number</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" [(ngModel)]="form.password" #password="ngModel"
              [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':f.submitted && password.invalid}" required minlength="6" placeholder="Create your password" [class.is-invalid]="password.invalid && password.touched"/>
            <div *ngIf="f.submitted && password.invalid" class="invalid-feedback">
              <div *ngIf="password.errors.required">>> required</div>
              <div *ngIf="password.errors.minlength">>> must be at least 6 characters</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="image">Image</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="myFile" (change)="fileEvent($event)" [(ngModel)]="form.myFile" #myFile="ngModel"/>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-success">Register</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: you have to create a object which consist of two things 1. Formdata 2.Extra data and send that object in URL.

Comment: remove action="/" from your form element.

Comment: yes , i am remove it...

Comment: how to write code please help me @iamrajshah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use shared service which is singlton service and with variable type of subject. And the other option you have you can use routing param.